# Power BI - find the sum of fields if other fields are equal

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to get the aging of objects over time, per "status". One of the status is "On Hold" any individual object can be on hold multiple times. (1 to many table relation in the DB). I have merged the two tables in power BI and I now want to find the total on hold duration. I have an SQL query to give it to me, but I am not sure how to do it inside of Power Bi.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    H.onhold_project,
    SUM(H.onhold_starttime) SUMSTART,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(H.onhold_endtime) < SUM(H.onhold_starttime) THEN SUM(H.onhold_endtime) + corefunc.ConvertDateToUnix(GETDATE(), -7)
        WHEN SUM(H.onhold_endtime) IS NULL THEN corefunc.ConvertDateToUnix(GETDATE(), -7)
        ELSE SUM(H.onhold_endtime)
    END SUMEND,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(H.onhold_endtime) < SUM(H.onhold_starttime) THEN (SUM(H.onhold_endtime) + corefunc.ConvertDateToUnix(GETDATE(), -7)) - SUM(H.onhold_starttime)
        WHEN SUM(H.onhold_endtime) IS NULL THEN corefunc.ConvertDateToUnix(GETDATE(), -7) - SUM(H.onhold_starttime)
        ELSE SUM(H.onhold_endtime) - SUM(H.onhold_starttime)
    END DURATION
FROM
    proj.onhold H
GROUP BY H.onhold_project
```

Notes:

all of the dates are in UNIX time format which I then convert into the microsoft epoch time for displaying.

ConvertDateToUnix is a stored function that converts Microsoft epoch time code to unix time stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out. Power BI has an option to use a SQL query to load the data. That way you can have your SQL and report it too.

I believe another way that it could work which I have not tried is use a View.

Answer (score 0):

If the sql query is giving what you need then, at most basic you just need to export the set to file, load the data in powerBI via get data, and then add all the fields into a matrix visualization.  Of course this process should be more elegant for ongoing business needs.